# A module generated by a set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have a ring $R$ and a set $S$, I want to generate a free module with coefficients from $R$, such that elements are linear expressions of the form $$r_1 s_1 + r_2 s_2 + ... + r_n s_n,$$ where $r_i \in R$ and $s_i \in S$.
Can I just say the free module of $R$ generated by the set $S$?

What I am confused about is that in the definition of a $R$-module, $S$ should have a group structure $(S,+)$. What if I do not have that, is it still well defined or do I get something that is not an $R$-module?

Answer (score 3):

What we call the free $R$-module generated by the set $S$ is defined exactly the way you describe it. However, be careful: It is not $S$ that ends up being the module, so $(S, +)$ doesn't make sense. There is (a priori) no addition on $S$, and we don't define an addition on $S$. The underlying set of this free module, where we define addition and scalar multiplication, is the set
$$
\{r_1s_1 + r_2s_2 + \cdots + r_ns_n\mid r_i\in R, s_i\in S\}
$$
where we don't worry too much about what the symbol "$+$" really means, and just let it be implicit that it behaves the way we want addition to behave, so that for instance the element $r_1s_1 + r_2s_2$ is the same as the element $r_2s_2 + r_1s_1$. These are called *formal* linear combinations.

We define addition the straight-forward way, with for instance
$$
(r_1s_1 + r_2s_2) + (r_3s_2 + r_4s_3) = r_1s_1 + (r_2+r_3)s_2 + r_4s_3
$$
(don't be confused; there are three different "$+$" symbols in there, meaning different things). Scalar multiplication is defined similarily:
$$
r_1\cdot (r_2s_2 + r_3s_3) = (r_1r_2)s_2 + (r_1r_3)s_3
$$
For instance, the module $R\times R$ may be interpreted as the free $R$-module generated by the set $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The free module generated by $S$ is the $R$-module 
$$R^{(S)}=\bigl\{f\colon S\to R\mid f(s)=0,\;\text{ but for a finite number of }s\bigr\},$$
in other words, it is the set of maps from $S$ to $R$ with *finite support*.

A basis of this $R$-module is the set of maps $\mathbf 1_s$ defined by
$$\mathbf 1_s(t)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }t\ne s,\\1&\text{if }t=s.\end{cases}$$
Usually, these maps are denoted $\;\mathbf 1_s=[s]$, so that a generic element of $R^{(S)}$ be denoted
$$\lambda_{1}[s_{1}]+\dots+ \lambda_{n}[s_{n}]$$
for some $n$.

If $S$ is a finite set, and $|S|=k$, then $R^{(S)}$ is (isomorphic to) $R^k$.

Note that the ring $R[X]$ of polynomials with coefficients in $R$ is defined as the $R$-module $R^{(\mathbf N)}$, on which a multiplicative structure is defined, so that it becomes an $R$-algebra.

Similarly, the ring of polynomials in $r$ indeterminates is the $R$-module $\;R^{(\mathbf N^r)}$ with a multiplicative structure.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this I can check out?

Answer (score 0):

It is still well defined. The confusion comes from the fact that $S$ is not the module itself, but is only an *index set* or *set of generators* for the free module. We *define* $(s_1) + (s_2)$ to be the symbol $(s_1+s_2)$. This means that for addition, you treat the elements $s_1 \ldots s_n$ like *basis vectors*. So, for example, $$(r_1 s_1 + r_2 s_2) + (r_3 s_2 + r_4s_3) = r_1 s_2 + (r_2+r_3)s_2 + r_3s_4.$$

An easy way to think about it is to think of your free module as being given by the set $R^S$ of functions $S \to R$. Then addition of functions and multiplication of functions by scalars (in $R$) give you the $R$-module structure.